# Deleting from linked list

Tags: c

I need to delete an item from my linked list.

I am willing to start at the front of the list by redirecting my header (called carbase) to the next one in the list.

When i run the function it does free the data of my struct. However, the pointer has not shifted.

```
struct carinfo_t *removeCarinfo(struct carinfo_t *carbase, char *merk, char 
*model, int year){
struct carinfo_t *curr = carbase;
while(curr != NULL){
int a, b, c;
a = strcmp(curr->brand, merk);
b = strcmp(curr->model, model);
c = curr->year;
if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == year){ //verwijderen wanneer dit waar is
    if(curr = carbase) //als het de eerste in de lijst is
    carbase = carbase->next;
    freeCarinfo(curr);
    return carbase;

}
curr = curr->next;
}

}
```

Comment: if(curr = carbase) is this right?

Answer (score 0):

Use a method like this one:

```
void deleteList(struct Node** head_ref) 
{ 
   /* deref head_ref to get the real head */
   struct Node* current = *head_ref; 
   struct Node* next; 

   while (current != NULL)  
   { 
       next = current->next; 
       free(current); 
       current = next; 
   } 

   /* deref head_ref to affect the real head back 
  in the caller. */
   *head_ref = NULL; 
}
```

You just need to pass the head Node reference here.

Comment: He needs to delete a particular item from list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the "carbase" pointer as the head cell of your struct, then try this:

```
struct carinfo_t *removeCarinfo(struct carinfo_t *carbase, char *merk, char*model, int year){
struct carinfo_t *curr = carbase;
while(curr->next != NULL){
    int a, b, c;
    a = strcmp(curr->next->brand, merk);
    b = strcmp(curr->next->model, model);
    c = curr->next->year;
    if (!a && !b && c == year){
        struct carinfo_t *aux = curr->next;
        curr->next = curr->next->next;
        free(aux);
}
curr = curr->next;
```

}